# How to pass field values as arguement to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a DB table in which one column have an array of values.
Lets assume

```
Student table
"Name" character(10),
"Subject_studying" text[],
```

I created a stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ArrayLike(vals text[], v text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  str text;
BEGIN
  v := replace(replace(v, '%', '.*'), '_', '.');
  FOREACH str IN ARRAY vals LOOP
    IF str ~* v THEN
      RETURN 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Which returns all the subjects that I'm looking for.
How do I pass the parameter of the subjects to the stored procedure.

My query looks like

```
SELECT Name FROM Student WHERE ArrayLike('Subject_studying', 'english') = 1
```

The query is giving me an error

```
 ERROR:  FOREACH expression must not be null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function Arraylike(text[],text) line 6 at FOREACH over array
********** Error **********
```

I guess the parameter 'Subject_studying' is not sent as a value but as a simple string. How do we pass the values in that field to the stored procedure?

Comment: Your query is definitely ill-quoted, should be `ArrayLike("Subject_studying", 'english')` (or, just omit double quotes everywhere, if you can -- quoting identifiers could easily get messy -- Postgres' docs also suggests that you should always use identifier quotation, or **never**). But of course, you should get a different error message if your only error was this. Is that a typo in your question, or that query actually produces that error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by passing the column name `subject_studying` as a string, as you already noted. Unquote it to make the error go away.

But you actually do not have to create your own function for this. You can use the built-in `ANY` operator:

```
SELECT Name FROM Student WHERE 'english' = ANY(subject_studying);
```

Comment: I want to apply like filter on array of fields. Someting like I want to find find students with subjects studying, Physics and physiology if I send arguement as "physi"


It gives me this error if I removed the quoted
`ERROR:  column "subject_studying" does not exist
LINE 15: AND ArrayLike(subject_studying, 'physi') = 1`

Comment: `ANY` won't work with pattern matching operators (if OP wants to test multiple values against a single pattern; the other way around (testing a single value for multiple patterns) can work with `ANY`).